# How to automate Google Cloud Deployment using Cloud Build and Compute Engine

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, deployment, continuous-integration, google-compute-engine

I have been setting up a CI/CD pipeline for my Express.js application and have made significant progress. However, I am encountering an issue with one of the crucial steps.

Here's what I've achieved so far:

1. GitHub Repository: I have created a GitHub repository to store my application code.
2. Cloud Build Integration: I've connected my GitHub repository to Cloud Build, which automatically builds a Docker image and pushes it to the Artifact Registry with each deployment.
3. Managed Instance Group: I created a Managed Instance Group with an instance template. This template uses the Docker image from the Artifact Registry to deploy the Express.js application.
4. Load Balancer Configuration: The instance group is connected to a load balancer, ensuring that the application is accessible at a static IP address.
   However, there's a crucial step I'm missing:

Rolling Update: I need to implement a rolling update process where, whenever a new Docker image is created in the Artifact Registry, the VMs in the compute instance group automatically update with the new image.
Currently, I'm using a cloudbuild.yaml file for my deployment process. In the final step of the process, I encounter an error:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gcloud, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Here's my cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
  # Step 0: Install packages
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args:
      - 'install'

  # Step 1: Build the Nest.js application
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args:
      - 'run'
      - 'build'

  # Step 2: Build the Docker image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'build'
      - '-t'
      - 'asia-south2-docker.pkg.dev/${MY_PROJECT_ID}/core-apis/core-apis:latest'
      - '.'

  # Step 3: Push the Docker image to the Artifact Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'push'
      - 'asia-south2-docker.pkg.dev/${MY_PROJECT_ID}/core-apis/core-apis:latest'

  # Step 4: Deploy the image to the managed instance group
  - name: 'gcloud'
    args:
      - 'compute'
      - 'instances'
      - 'update'
      - '--zone'
      - 'us-central1-c'
      - 'core-apis'
      - '--scopes'
      - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
      - '--image'
      - 'asia-south2-docker.pkg.dev/${MY_PROJECT_ID}/core-apis/core-apis'

options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
substitutions:
  _NAME: 'core-apis'
```

Comment: You might be missing permission to read the registry on the account you use to deploy. Ensure that you have provided all sufficient permissions.

Comment: @AlishSatani I have given Cloud Build service account the Artifact Reader Registry Permission, and for good measure I have also given it the Artifact Registry Admin permission as well, still receiving the same error

Comment: Please follow this documentation on [building and testing Node.js applications](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-nodejs) as you may have missed some steps. It seems that it requires `entrypoint: 'npm'` as all of your project's dependencies are installed from `npm`.